# Laravel filter and sort a collection based on conditions

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections, filtering

I have a collection for example with these details:

```
collect([
                        [
                            'id'       => 1,
                            'bankName' => 'Dare-Schmitt',
                            'pmt'      => 47068.084449396,
                            'period'   => 240
                        ],
                        [
                            'id'       => 2,
                            'bankName' => 'Dare-Schmitt',
                            'pmt'      => 45989.430695784,
                            'period'   => 180
                        ],
                        [
                            'id'       => 3,
                            'bankName' => 'Dare-Schmitt',
                            'pmt'      => 55459.759785392,
                            'period'   => 240
                        ],
                        [
                            'id'       => 4,
                            'bankName' => 'Lorenzo-Platto',
                            'pmt'      => 37068.084449396,
                            'period'   => 50
                        ]
                    ]
            );
```

I need to sort and filter them by show only one record for same bankName where the pmt is the highest and just check it on where the period is the same.

So based on the example after filtering and sorting I have to got back this result:

```
        collect([
                    [
                        'id'       => 2,
                        'bankName' => 'Dare-Schmitt',
                        'pmt'      => 45989.430695784,
                        'period'   => 180
                    ],
                    [
                        'id'       => 3,
                        'bankName' => 'Dare-Schmitt',
                        'pmt'      => 55459.759785392,
                        'period'   => 240
                    ],
                    [
                        'id'       => 4,
                        'bankName' => 'Lorenzo-Platto',
                        'pmt'      => 37068.084449396,
                        'period'   => 50
                    ]
                ]
        );
```

Any idea how to achive this? I lost a bit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collection [method-groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) to make records with same `backName` and same `period` in group.

And use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) get the highest `pmt` record:

```php
$data->groupBy(function ($g) {
       return $g['bankName'].' '.$g['period'];
     })->map(function($items) { 
        return $items->sortByDesc('pmt')->first(); // get the highest pmt record
     })->values();
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your help! :)

It is almost good just one other problem left If I try this solution on the above example collection also the Dare-Schmitt bank with 180 period is falling out from the result list and I need it too also.

Comment: @Wathfea so u want to get the highest pmr for same bankName and same period? I have updated the answer.

Comment: Almost The collection has other attributes
So what I need based on the user input (period) for example 240 the bank with all of it details with the highest pmt between the same periods. 
Example:
`1, Name Test, pmt 1, period 240, color red etc
2, Name Test, pmt 2, period 240, color green etc
3, Name Test, pmt 1, period 180, color blue etc
4, Name Foo, pmt 1, period 60, color red etc`

After the filtering
`1, Name Test, pmt 2, period 240, color green etc
2, Name Test, pmt 1, period 180, color blue etc
3, Name Foo, pmt 1, period 60, color red etc`

Filtered out the first bank

Comment: Sorry my bad. It is working fine! :) Thank you so much